# Unique color for zero values in pyplot TwoSlopeNorm LinearSegmentedColormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'd like to use a custom (blue) color on a plot where the data is zero. I have tried the set_under method, but failed. The desired output would be a blue line at the bottom and a two blue square at the upper part of the graph. Any help is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap,TwoSlopeNorm

# TwoSlopeNorm see:
# https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormapnorms-py
red2orange = np.array([np.linspace(1, 1, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 165/256, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 0, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
grey2black = np.array([np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
all_colors = np.vstack((grey2black,red2orange))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('two_slope_cmap', all_colors)
divnorm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=1, vcenter=400, vmax=1000)

# seting bad and under
cmap.set_bad('mediumspringgreen')
cmap.set_under('blue')

#fake data
data = np.arange(1400)[:,None]* np.ones(200)
data[ 1100:1150, 50:150] = np.nan # bad data
data[ 1200:1250, 50:150] = 0 # zero data
data[ 1300:1350, 50:150] = -1 # under data

# plot
f,a = plt.subplots()
raster = a.pcolormesh(data,cmap=cmap, norm=divnorm)
cbar = f.colorbar(raster,ax=a, extend='both')
```

[image]

Comment: For some unknown reason, `TwoSlopeNorm` doesn't seem to honor the `under` nor `over` colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason, `TwoSlopeNorm` doesn't seem to honor the `under` nor `over` colors. Changing the code to use `plt.Normalize()` instead of `TwoSlopeNorm()` indicates that for that norm, the `under` color works as expected.

A workaround is to draw the `pcolormesh` a second time, only for the `under` color. A drawback is that the under color isn't shown in the colorbar extension.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap, TwoSlopeNorm

red2orange = np.array([np.linspace(1, 1, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 165 / 256, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 0, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
grey2black = np.array([np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
all_colors = np.vstack((grey2black, red2orange))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('two_slope_cmap', all_colors)
divnorm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=1, vcenter=400, vmax=1000)

# seting bad and under
cmap.set_bad('mediumspringgreen')
cmap.set_under('dodgerblue')  # this doesn't seem to be used with a TwoSlopeNorm

# fake data
data = np.arange(1400)[:, None] * np.ones(200)
data[1100:1150, 50:150] = np.nan  # bad data
data[1200:1250, 50:150] = 0  # zero data
data[1300:1350, 50:150] = -1  # under data

# plot
f, a = plt.subplots()
raster = a.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cmap, norm=divnorm)
cbar = f.colorbar(raster, ax=a, extend='both')

# draw the mesh a second time, only for the under color
a.pcolormesh(np.where(data < 1, 0, np.nan), cmap=ListedColormap([cmap.get_under()]))

plt.show()
```

[image: mimicking under color for TwoSlopeNorm by drawing twice]

Another workaround is to change the colormap itself, setting the lowest color to the desired under color. A drawback is that `vmin` needs to move a bit. (The distance seems to be 1/127 of the distance between vmin and vcenter. Internally, the colormap maintains 256 colors, with the color for vcenter at position 128.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, TwoSlopeNorm, to_rgba

red2orange = np.array([np.linspace(1, 1, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 165 / 256, 256),
                       np.linspace(0, 0, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
grey2black = np.array([np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.linspace(0.75, 0.25, 256),
                       np.ones(256)]).T
all_colors = np.vstack((grey2black, red2orange))
all_colors[0, :] = to_rgba('dodgerblue')
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('two_slope_cmap', all_colors)
vmin = 1
vcenter = 400
vmax = 1000
divnorm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=vmin-(vcenter-vmin)/127, vcenter=vcenter, vmax=vmax)

# seting bad and under
cmap.set_bad('mediumspringgreen')
cmap.set_under('red')  # this doesn't seem to be used with a TwoSlopeNorm

# fake data
data = np.arange(1400)[:, None] * np.ones(200)
data[1100:1150, 50:150] = np.nan  # bad data
data[1200:1250, 50:150] = 0  # zero data
data[1300:1350, 50:150] = -1  # under data

# plot
f, a = plt.subplots()
raster = a.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cmap, norm=divnorm)
cbar = f.colorbar(raster, ax=a, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image: mimicking set_under for TwoSlopeNorm]

PS: The following code tries to visualize how the two norms treat the `under` color differently:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 3))

data = np.arange(0, 100)[:, None]
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis').copy()
cmap.set_under('crimson')
cmap.set_over('skyblue')

norm1 = plt.Normalize(20, 80)
im1 = ax1.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm1, aspect='auto', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1, extend='both')
ax1.set_title('using plt.Normalize()')

norm2 = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=20, vcenter=30, vmax=80)
im2 = ax2.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm2, aspect='auto', origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, extend='both')
ax2.set_title('using TwoSlopeNorm')

plt.show()
```

[image: TwoSlopeNorm doesn't honor set_under color]

PPS: Looking into the source of TwoSlopeNorm at github, the problem seems to be solved for the next version of matplotlib (current version is 3.4.3). So, you could try to install the development version. (The change involves adding `left=-np.inf, right=np.inf` as parameter to `np.interp` in the `__call__` method of the `TwoSlopeNorm` class in `colors.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer!  With your workaround, any value under 4  became blue instead of the expected zero-or-smaller values only.  (Try: data[1300:1350, 50:150] = 4  # under data.) I can magically correct this behavior by setting vmin to -3 (divnorm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-3, vcenter=400, vmax=1000), but I don't know the origin of this magic offsetter. I'm a bit afraid, it will produce inconsistent results if I produce a few thousand plots with different data ranges and TwoSlopeNorm parameters. Could you please comment on my worries before closing this question as fully solved?

Comment: I updated the answer with an approach to draw the mesh a second time. And another approach moving vmin.